# Global scope of nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am developing a commentbox which contain multi-level comments (like reddit)

So here is the hierachy :

```
// all are directive nesting each other
commentbox > comments >comment [> comments >comment].....  

// under commentbox  & each comment is commentForm
commentbox   > commentForm
comment     > commentForm
```

So I want to pass enable = false to commentBox to disable all commentForm at any level. And I have no idea how to  access **scope.enabled**  of **commentBox** from anywhere within the hierarchy tree , e.g **comment@lvl2>commentForm** .

So if the screen has 20 commentBox, each should have it own $directiveRootscope.enabled , accessible to all children directives

Comment: Use a service to manage the interactions between multiple directives, or use $emit/$broadcast to communicate to other directives, or use $parent to access parent scope variables via children scopes.

Comment: @mdlars : service cannot help because my screen have 20 commentBox. $emit/broadcast, may work. I will try it

Comment: @Pham a service can help.  All your directives can bind to the same property off the same service.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams but I need to enable some commentbox while disable some others. Broadcast won't work neither as it require user action to fire.  What I need it kinda $directiveRootscope.enabled = true

Comment: You can use a property parent on each object, and a function like: isDisabled = function() { return disabled || (parent && parent.isDisabled()); }